# How to compare two view models with same property and if the value of a property is different add that property to different list?

Tags: c#

Lets say I have two view models.

**View model 1:**

```
public string Name {get;set;} = Harry
public int Age {get;set;} = 19
public string Address {get;set;} = Somewhere
public string PhoneNumber {get;set;} = 1234567899
```

**View model 2:**

```
public string Name {get;set;} = Harry
public int Age {get;set;} = 19
public string Address {get;set;} = Here
public string PhoneNumber {get;set;} = 1234567899
```

So as you can you see value of the property Address is different. My question is how do we compare these two view models and as you can see Address value is different and I need Address property to be added to list after comparing these two viewmodels.

Comment: Why don't you just use: `if(view1.Address != view2.Address){ list.Add(view1.Address);}` Irs or that simple or that I didn't get you right. If so, please explain more.

Comment: I have a similar type of class with 40-50 property. It will be really long. The solution you gave is 100% correct but there are a lot of property.

Comment: The thing is i need to check all of the property.

Comment: *"need Address property to be added to list"* - this sounds like [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/299295). You can't add *property* to a list, rather its value, name or perhaps `PropertyInfo`. How are you going to use this list containing `Address` property?

Answer (score 0):

If you need a list of differences you can take it with: (where Model is your **View Model class**)

```
public static List<string> GetDifferences(Model first, Model second) =>
    typeof(Model).GetProperties()
        .Where(property => property.GetValue(first) != property.GetValue(second))
        .Select(property => property.Name)
        .ToList();
```

Same method without LINQ:

```
public static List<string> GetDifferences(Model first, Model second)
{
    var result = new List<string>();

    foreach (var property in typeof(Model).GetProperties())
    {
        if (property.GetValue(first) != property.GetValue(second))
        {
            result.Add(property.Name);
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Reflection has poor performance, you could/should tweak that code to only call `GetProperties()` once per type so several calls to GetDifferences with the same types do not perform poorly

Comment: True. But in other way should compare all 40-50 properties one by one: if(view1.Address != view2.Address){ list.Add(view1.Address);} and so on.

Comment: I get your point, and I am not suggesting not doing what you suggest. I am suggesting how to improve your code

Comment: Thanks for the solution. It helped me solve the problem and I have tweak the code little bit to avoid poor performance.